# HeadlessChrome browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues in Testcafe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, testcafe, webautomation

Chrome headless browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues in testcafe in ubuntu

I have executed testcafe scripts with the command

`testcafe chrome:headless AbcTest.js`

Following is the error message received after few minutes of execution

`ERROR The HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 / Linux 0.0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.`

Comment: Have you tried to run your tests in the regular (non-headless) mode? Can you make a screenshot of the browser at the moment it gets disconnected?

Comment: I have updated chrome to the latest version in Jenkins and it works fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndreyBelym It again started to hang for some reason and it is not reproducible in the same step. One time it hangs after 1 hour of execution and other time it hangs after 2.30 hours of execution.

Comment: @AndreyBelym I'm also experiencing this issue more frequently. I'm using TestCafe 1.4.1 (-c 3, with quarantine mode) and chrome 76.0.3.... 1 thing I have noticed is that despite using -c 3, no results are posted back to the console until ALL tests have passed. I'm not able to reproduce running in headed mode. I can email you if you require further info

Comment: @Rob C
We would love to assist you and diagnose this issue. However, our policy prevents us from accessing internal resources without prior written approval from a site owner. If you want us to further research the problem directly on your side, please ask the website owner to send us (mailto:support@devexpress.com) a written confirmation. It must permit DevExpress personnel to remotely access the website and its internal resources for research/testing/and debugging purposes.

Comment: I was also getting the same error while trying to run Testcafe tests in Docker with `firefox:headless`.

`ERROR The Firefox 68.0 / Linux 0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear 
when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.
Type "testcafe -h" for help.`

As `meraj-ahmed` mentioned in the below link. 

https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/2194#issuecomment-438803326

Removing `maximizeWindow()` method from the test worked for me.